# Memory Leak in Android application

Tags: android, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I have a class structure that looks like this.

```
class A
    {
        B b;

        A()
        {
            b = new B();
            b.a = this;
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        A a;
    }

    class C
    {
        A a = new A();

        //a is ready for Garbage collection
        a = null;
    }
```

On activity Destroy(), I will set the variable a = null. But on heap, still I could see that variable b holds the reference for B.

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Maybe it just haven't been collected yet. Tried forcing the gc?

Comment: @Memme Forcing a gc is a bad idea! You need to stop the memory leak not try and cover it up.

Comment: @apmartin1991 of course. But I would have checked it just to be sure. Anyways the fact that you instantiate a new object in C and put it to null will collect that specific instance only. But I might be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, non-static inner and anonymous classes hold an implicit
>   reference to their outer class. Static inner classes, on the other
>   hand, do not.

So if for example you are doing a long running operation on classes B or C, that will prevent the activity context from being garbage collected and leaking all of
the application’s resources.

[Here is a great post about memory leaking on Android with static inner classes, written by Alex Lockwood](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)

Another potential reason can be that you are not handling correctly background threads and these are still executed or have been scheduled for future execution. As Alex Lockwood has written on [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html):

> Don’t assume that Java will ever clean up your running threads for you.

Finally, you can integrate [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) which is a great tool for memory leak detection. It'll show you with a graph what object holds a reference and prevents garbage collection.

Comment: True, but there are no inner or nested classes in this code